# Deadlock implementation doesn't work without Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

I'm trying to understand deadlocks and accordingly attempting to create an implementation of deadlock.
The idea is to create a simulation of cyclic locking. Here's my `Runnable` implementation:

```
public class WorkDelegator implements Runnable {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getGlobal();

WorkDelegator workDelegatorSupplier;
private final String name;

public WorkDelegator(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setWorkDelegatorSupplier(WorkDelegator workDelegatorSupplier) {
    this.workDelegatorSupplier = workDelegatorSupplier;
}

public void delegate(){

    synchronized (workDelegatorSupplier) {
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(300);
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                LOGGER.warning("InterruptedException in Task " + name);
//            }
        workDelegatorSupplier.delegate();
    }
    LOGGER.info("task delegated from " + name + "to " + workDelegatorSupplier);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    LOGGER.info(this + " is trying to delegate task to " + workDelegatorSupplier);
    delegate();
}
}
```

A bunch of `WorkDelegator` instances cyclically delegating work on each other by calling `delegate` void. The point is that it works properly if commented out code is executing too, but why I get `StackOverflowError` without Thread sleeping?

PS - Delegator Factory class:

```
public class WorkDelegatorFactory {

public List<WorkDelegator> getDelegatorsList(int size) {

    List<WorkDelegator> workDelegatorList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
        workDelegatorList.add(new WorkDelegator(String.valueOf(i)));
    }
    WorkDelegator firstDelegator = workDelegatorList.get(0);
    WorkDelegator lastDelegator = workDelegatorList.get(size-1);
    lastDelegator.setWorkDelegatorSupplier(firstDelegator);
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        workDelegatorList.get(i).setWorkDelegatorSupplier(workDelegatorList.get(i+1));
    }
    return workDelegatorList;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `sleep` the first thread to launch can do a lot of recursive calls before the others start. This allows them to grab enough of the synchronization locks to continue indefinitely and eventually run out of stack depth. Other threads started arrive too late to grab their first synchronization lock and just sit idle.

With the `sleep` each thread can only grab one synchronization lock and no thread can get so far ahead that it can loop.

What you are seeing is the one of the hard parts of concurrent programming: you know the sequence in each thread but not where each thread is in relation to the others.

Comment: Which is why I often use a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to get threads at the same starting point before executing the part that needs testing. Not perfect (OS scheduler can still decide to let one thread stand still), but usually enough to get a "hit" more often than a "miss".